# How to generate a PDF with multiple page breaks?

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdf

I want to create a PDF using HTML, PHP, and MySQL and I want a new page every time a new row is fetched and then generate a combined PDF for all the pages created.

How can I achieve this?

```
<?php
$count=0; 
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root",""); 
mysqli_select_db($con, "electricity"); 
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT acct, name, address, amount FROM newtable"); 
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
{
?>
<html>
<body><pre>
    श्री:   <?php echo $row['name'];?><br>
    पता:   <?php echo $row['address'];?>            
ACCNO :- <b><?php echo $row['acct'];?></b>
Amount : <b><?php $val=$row['amount']+25; echo $val;?></b>
</pre>
</body>
</html>
<?php
} 
mysqli_close($con); 
?>
```

Comment: where's do you involve any PDF lib ? as it is now, your code doesn't create any pdf file

Comment: @Pierre It does not create any pdf now, i wanted to know what is the simplest way to do so?

Comment: There 's TCPDF which works nice. Available on tcpdf.org

Answer (score 0):

I used FPDF many times and it allows you to do whatever you want. Have more info here for doc & download link : http://www.fpdf.org/?lang=en